# Returning all the hastags with regex in php?

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

My goal is to take a string that contains hashtags and return all the hashtags.

My function:

```
function get_hashtags($text)
{
    preg_match("/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/", $text, $matches);
    return $matches;

}
```

Currently when I try

```
$text = "yay this is #my comment and it's #awesome and cool";
$tag = get_hashtags($text);
print_r($tag);
```

I get:
Array ( [0] => #my [1] => [2] => my )

I just would like to return an array such as

```
array('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3');
```

Without the actual #

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you

EDIT:
Someone posted an anaswer but it disapeared, it is exactly what I wanted however now I get an error, code:

```
function get_hashtags($text)
{
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/", $text, $matches);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $result[] = $match[2];
    }
    return $result;


}
```

The error is: Undefined offset: 2

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Try using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$text = "yay this is #my comment and it's #awesome and cool";
preg_match_all("/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/", $text, $matches); // updated to use original regex

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preg_match_all` if you want all the tags back. The way the preg matching functions work though they are always going to return the complete match as well as what you are attempting to capture so you wont be able to jsut return `$matches` directly.

```
function get_hashtags($text)
{
    preg_match_all("/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/", $text, $matches);

    return $matches[2];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\#)[^\s]+/', $text, $matches);
```

For the `$text` value you specified, `$matches[0]` will contain only the words after a hash by using a negative-look behind, which matches the hash, but excludes it from the results.

The section `[^\s]+` you can essentially replace with anything, in this example it will match any non-whitespace character, if you need it to match only word characters and underscores you can use Tim's example `[a-zA-Z_]+`